# Functions with $R^2$ and $S^2$

Tags: functions

Suppose I have a function which takes as arguments 3 real numbers x,y,z and spits out 2 real numbers

$f[x,y,z]=[a,b]$

My question is: when can such a function be thought as taking values on the sphere $S^2$ instead of $R^2$?

Because I know that, by sterographic projection, one can map the whole $S^2$ to $R^2$, except the point at the north pole.

Then, assuming that as we vary x,y,z, the image of f does not blow [that is, neither a or b go to infinity] can I think of this function as taking values on $S^2$ instead of $R^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$You can't think of $f$ *itself* as a map to the sphere, but if $\pi^{-1}:\Reals^{2} \to S^{2}$ is the inverse of stereographic projection, the composition $\pi^{-1} \circ f:\Reals^{3} \to S^{2}$ takes values in the sphere.

Comment: I see..so because the image of f, (a,b) does not blow up, the inverse stereographic projection is well defined...and then the composite map of inverse stereographic projection and f gives me a map from $R^3$ to $S^2$ right?

Comment: Yes: If the image of $f$ is contained in $\Reals^{2}$ ("the image does not blow up"), the composition $\pi^{-1} \circ f$ sends $\Reals^{3}$ to $S^{2}$.